# Cannot locate element using actions as UIAutomatorviewer does not show all elements

Tags: selenium, appium, appium-ios, appium-android, uiautomatorviewer

UIautomatorviewer does not break down the page to detect element, the whole page is shown as one window.

I have tried identifying elements using following but no luck when try to run the code

**Xpaths**

```
driver.findElementByXPath("//android.webkit.WebView[@text='LOG IN']").click();
driver.findElementByXPath("//android.webkit.WebView[@bounds='[1242,84][1424,87]']").click();
```

**Ids**

```
driver.findElementById("com.abc.mobileapp:id/Login").click();
driver.findElementById("com.abc.mobileapp:id/id8").click();
```

---

Some background - this app has multiple webviews.

I am just giving a try, will be using python appium client or java appium client for final script.

---

Attached a screenshot after removing some details about the app. (as you can see from screenshot, only one view is captured with all details) [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfYdS.png)

---

Have tried a lot of ways of finding element but always get an error "unable to locate element with method..."

will be helpful if can provide tips so we can try to change the source code so this app can be automated.

---

Appreciate your thought and help people. Thanks a lot..

Comment: If the element is in webview then switch to that webview and then try.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to use appium desktop where u will get lot options to inspect element.
2. Find below screenshots to followup accessing appium desktop

**Open appium desktop**
[image]

**Start appium server**
[image]

**click on start new session**
[image]

**add android capabilities**
[image]

**start to view ui view**
[image]

**try to inspect elements**
[image]